# .Net Maui notification badge number not showing

Tags: android, .net, maui

Android API 29 and 33: badge number not showing
I couldnt find in Notification Settings the App Icon Badges Show with number.
What should I do?

notification settings:

```
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
                MainApplication.ChannelId)
            .SetContentText(input)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.AppIcon)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        BadgeNumber++;
        notification.SetNumber(BadgeNumber);
        notification.SetContentTitle("Service Running");
        StartForeground(myId, notification.Build());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Let us first read up on this at [Create a Notification](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification)

We can use `NotificationCompat` to create the builder and it works on API level 26 and above. So the least we need to do if you are going to do this from a service:

```cs
var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, $"{this.PackageName}.channel");
builder.SetContentTitle("Service Started");
builder.SetContentText("");
builder.SetAutoCancel(false);
builder.SetSmallIcon(global::Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogAlert);
builder.SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityDefault);
var notification = builder.Build();
var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
notificationManager?.Notify((int)DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds(), notification);
```

We also need to check for permissions and ask to turn on the Notification if it is turned off. [Notification runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission)

You need to add

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>`

to Android [Manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring)

Now we need code to check and ask permission if needed.

> Before your app sends a notification, confirm whether the user has enabled notifications for your app. To do so, call areNotificationsEnabled().

```cs
private void CheckAndOpenNotificationSettings()
{
    var currentActivity = Platform.CurrentActivity;

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);

    if (!notificationManager.AreNotificationsEnabled())
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity);
        builder.SetTitle("Enable Notifications");
        builder.SetMessage("Notifications are currently disabled for this app. Would you like to enable them?");
        builder.SetPositiveButton("Yes", (sender, args) =>
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetAction(global::Android.Provider.Settings.ActionAppNotificationSettings);

            // For Android 5-7
            intent.PutExtra(global::Android.Provider.Settings.ExtraAppPackage, PackageName);

            // For Android 8 and above
            intent.PutExtra(global::Android.Provider.Settings.ExtraChannelId, ApplicationInfo.Uid);

            currentActivity.StartActivity(intent);
        });
        builder.SetNegativeButton("No", (sender, args) =>
        {
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create();
        dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

This is it. I hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

You don't have to increment the badge number. It is incremented for you so dont't use SetNumber unless you want to set an actual number.

Answer (score 0):

From document [Modify a notification badge](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/badges#:%7E:text=To%20set%20a%20custom%20number%2C%20call%20setNumber%20%28%29,here%3A%20Kotlin%20Java%20var%20notification%20%3D%20NotificationCompat.Builder%28this%40MainActivity%2C%20CHANNEL_ID%29):

> Starting with Android 8.0 (API level 26), notification badges—also
> known as notification dots—appear on a launcher icon when the
> associated app has an active notification. Users can `touch & hold` the
> app icon to reveal the notifications, along with any app shortcuts, as
> shown in figure 1.

[image]

So, if you call code `notification.SetNumber(BadgeNumber);` for your Notification, you can touch and hold the app icon to reveal the notification. There you can find the number you set.

You can also check the official sample here: [Android Local Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/localnotifications/).

For more information, please check : [Using local notifications in Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough).